# Proxychains unable to connect to website

Tags: kali-linux, proxychains

Trying to get proxychains setup using vm with kali, i enter proxychains firefox google.com into terminal and after a while firefox says timeout, is this to do with the proxy server being down or smt else.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the proxyserver down or misconfigured. Check `/etc/proxychains.conf`

Comment: Thanks, just out of interest what should i be looking for in /etc/proxychains.conf

Comment: Whether the configuration fits your needs (Socks, proxy ip/port). You need a proxy/socks host to use and have to configure it.

Comment: ah okay thank you